# Spring, autowire @Value from a database

Tags: spring, configuration-files

I am using a properties File to store some configuration properties, that are accessed this way:

```
@Value("#{configuration.path_file}")
private String pathFile;
```

Is it possible (with Spring 3) to use the same `@Value` annotation, but loading the properties from a database instead of a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a table in your database stored key/value pairs:

Define a new bean "applicationProperties" - psuedo-code follows...

```
public class ApplicationProperties {
    @AutoWired
    private DataSource datasource;

    public getPropertyValue(String key) {
        // transact on your datasource here to fetch value for key
        // SNIPPED
    }
}
```

Inject this bean where required in your application.  If you already have a dao/service layer then you would just make use of that.

Comment: Thank you, but the application is already annotated with @Value annotations, so I'd like to avoid changing the code.  Do you think it is possible to keep @Value("#{configuration.path_file}") and tell Spring "hey, when I use #{configuration.path_file} I want you to call ApplicationProperties.getPath_file· or something like that ?
This way I can keep the current code untouched.

Comment: What is satisfying the dependency then?  Is the class responsible for loading the properties file itself?

Comment: It works, using a @Bean.  The only problem is that a change in the DB value is not reflected, as the value is injected only once, thus keeping the initial value.  I suppose this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can keep your @Value annotation, and use the database source with the help of [EnvironmentPostProcessor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor).

> As of Spring Boot 1.3, we're able to use the EnvironmentPostProcessor to customize the application's Environment before application context is refreshed.

For example, create a class which implements EnvironmentPostProcessor:

```
public class ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "databaseProperties";

    private String[] CONFIGS = {
            "app.version"
            // list your properties here
    };

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            // the following db connections properties must be defined in application.properties
            DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .username(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                    .password(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                    .url(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                    .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .build();

            try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                 // suppose you have a config table storing the properties name/value pair
                 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT value FROM config WHERE name = ?")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < CONFIGS.length; i++) {
                    String configName = CONFIGS[i];
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, configName);

                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        propertySource.put(configName, rs.getString("value"));
                    }

                    // rs.close();
                    preparedStatement.clearParameters();
                }
            }

            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, propertySource));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to put your `spring.factories` in META-INF. An example:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
  com.baeldung.environmentpostprocessor.autoconfig.PriceCalculationAutoConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not having used spring 3, I'd assume you can, if you make a bean that reads the properties from the database and exposes them with getters.